# Как сделать выгрузку DataFrame в CSV файл?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, pandas, dataframe, csv

Сначала идет обработка DataFrame, она работает нормально, проверила через `print()`.

```
таблица_на_выгрузку = (таблица.groupby([таблица["столбец"]])).sum().reset_index()
таблица_на_выгрузку['новый_столбец'] = 5*таблица.столбец
```

Далее я пытаюсь выгрузить файл, с помощью `.to_csv`, но в файл выгружается неправильно. Все данные и столбцы загружаются в 1 столбец и также загружается пустой столбец, который обозначает нумерацию.

```
таблица_на_выгрузку.to_csv(r'C:\путь\название_файла для выгрузки.csv', sep=',')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы все столбцы распределялись отдельно по своим местам, и чтобы пустой столбец с нумерацией не записывался в CSV файл?

Также подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы путь генерировался автоматически, так как данное приложение будет закачиваться на сервер и использоваться, как веб-приложение на других ПК.

Comment: Можете пояснит эту часть - `чтобы все столбцы распределялись отдельно по своим местам` ?

Comment: то есть например у нас есть 3 столбца в датафрейм(Country, State, City) и 3 столбца соответственно в excel (A, B, C). это значит, что столбец Country и его все строчки записался в A, а State в B и тд. У меня все сейчас записывается таким образом: 3 столбца от dataframe записываются только в колонку A excel и все его строчки также все в 1 столбец. (выглядит так: ,Country,State,City)

Comment: Путь можно генерировать автоматически если вы уверены, что директория, в которую вы хотите сохранить CSV файл точно существует на сервере. Мы ничего не знаем ни о сервере ни о том куда (на сервере) вы хотите сохранять CSV файл - можете прояснить эту часть также?

Comment: Так может вам стоит сохранять DataFrame сразу как Excel файл??

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, я пока тоже не знаю :( я тогда когда буду уже загружать на сервер подправлю код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по уточнениям из комментариев автору вопроса в итоге нужен Excel файл...

```
df.to_excel(r"/path/to/filename.xlsx", index=False)
```

В качестве альтернативы можно попробовать сохранить CSV файл с `";"` в качестве разделителя и попробовать открыть его в Excel:

```
df.to_csv(r"/path/to/filename.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я указала не тот сепаратор оказывается

Answer (score 2):

Вторую часть вопроса сделать несложно. Для этого есть специальный параметр.
Вот решение:

```
таблица_на_выгрузку.to_csv(r'C:\путь\название_файла для выгрузки.csv', sep=',', index = False)
```

Рекомендую прежде чем задавать вопрос,  запускать help() для интересующей вас функци, метода, класса...

```
 help(df.to_csv)
```

узнаете много интересного

Comment: я так пробовала, я этот способ указала в вопросе самом. У меня он не работает правильно

Comment: @MRO, в коде в вопросе вы не указали параметр `index=False` - это важно

Comment: я просто и так, и так пробовала и не сработало

Comment: @MRO, если указать этот параметр то не будет "первого пустого столбца с нумерацией"